How do I deny access to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK?
I've followed the example here to start a process and read the output, and have read through the information and examples here to change the anonymous pipe to a named pipe in order to read the input asynchronously. So far, so good.
However, on the second page, there's a remark about remote access:

Named pipes can be used to provide communication between processes on the same computer or between processes on different computers across a network. If the server service is running, all named pipes are accessible remotely. If you intend to use a named pipe locally only, deny access to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK or switch to local RPC.

As this pipe is being used solely for reading a launched program's output, I am using the named pipe locally only (even though the program does communicate with the network in other situations). However, I can't figure out how to deny access to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK. How do I do that? There are no links on the page, and Google hasn't helped me any further, either. Or, is it by any chance enough if I've set the PIPE_REJECT_REMOTE_CLIENTS flag in the dwPipeMode argument of CreateNamedPipe (although I'm assuming not)?
In case necessary, here is a rough outline of the code in question with error handling omitted for simplicity:
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attr;
attr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
attr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
attr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
HANDLE event = CreateEvent(&attr, TRUE, TRUE, NULL);
OVERLAPPED overlap;
overlap.hEvent = event;
overlap.Offset = 0;
overlap.OffsetHigh = 0;
HANDLE pipeHandle{ CreateNamedPipeW(
    pipename.c_str(),
    PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT | PIPE_REJECT_REMOTE_CLIENTS, 
    1, 
    BUFSIZE * sizeof(TCHAR), 
    BUFSIZE * sizeof(TCHAR), 
    5000, 
    &attr
    )};
BOOL connected = ConnectNamedPipe(pipeHandle, &overlap);
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION info;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));
si.hStdError = pipeHandle;
si.hStdOutput = pipeHandle;
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
CreateProcessW(
    exe.c_str(), 
    command.data(), 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    TRUE, 
    CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    &si, 
    &info);
HANDLE job = CreateJobObjectW(NULL, NULL);
AssignProcessToJobObject(job, info.hProcess);
ResumeThread(info.hThread);
CloseHandle(pipeHandle);
HANDLE file = CreateFileW(
    pipename.c_str(), 
    GENERIC_READ, 
    0, 
    NULL, 
    OPEN_EXISTING, 
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
    NULL);
DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
CHAR buf[BUFSIZE];
BOOL success = FALSE;
HANDLE waitHandles[] = {info.hProcess, cancelSimulation, overlap.hEvent};
DWORD procResult{};
while (true) {
    //monitor with WaitForMultipleObjects 
    //and handle the thread being cancelled, the process exiting, and stdout getting data
}


FYI, C++ language has a bool data type and C doesn't.  Since you tagged as C++, you should use the bool data type, not BOOL.

@ThomasMatthews I'm not sure that's ideal for working with the Windows API---I'm sure the ConnectNameedPipe call is to an API function which is defined to return BOOL and not bool.  (It's more applicable to success which isn't shown to interact with an API type, though I imagine that might be used in an unshown API call.)

@Craig correct, the win32 APIs generally use BOOL. As far as I can tell the Win32 APIs are actually C APIs, even though Microsoft always tags them with C++. To be sure, I use BOOL when interacting with the win32 libraries, and bool otherwise, just to be sure (although I'm not sure it makes a difference).

you can simply create security decriptor for pipe. but better - use anonymous pipes - it also can be asyncronous of course (name not affect this) and not possible open pipe by name if it hve no name

On a side note: Overlapped I/O on anonymous pipe

@Remy Lebeau I had also looked at that solution, but it just seems to create a named pipe which it then passes off as an anonymous pipe - but the named pipe still exists, right? Or am I understanding something wrong? I would have used an anonymous pipe, but everything I read said that anonymous pipes don't support overlapped I/O.

@RbMm thanks for the security descriptor keyword - now I'm able to find some documentation. Will have a go at it tomorrow.

@BenjaminKrausseDB - anonymous pipes don't support overlapped I/O - this is absolute nonsense. not exist anonymous pipes and named pipes. exist only pipes and all. what name of pipe - not play any role. and not need create random named pipes. possible create exactly unnnamed pipe pair

Or am I understanding something wrong? - complete wrong

According to the Microsoft documentation, "Asynchronous (overlapped) read and write operations are not supported by anonymous pipes." Am I mixing up terms or something?

@BenjaminKrausseDB - i know better than Microsoft documentation - here is full lie. not exist at all any anonymous pipes. exist only pipes and all. and pipes support asio

in general case, possible set appropriate security descriptor on object. as example we can get own logon sid and let access to object only for this sid. so only processes in your LogonSession can open object. (of course elevated admins/system can anyway found way of open such object).
but in concrete your case - you not need have name on pipe (begin from some version of win 7). possible create unnamed pipe pair (before this really unnamed pipe pairs not exist at all - system api create random named pair, but not true unnamed). and note exist only single type of pipe - pipe. what name of pipe (even if it empty) not change type and capabilites of object.
can be next code used for create unnamed pair:
NTSTATUS CreatePipePair(_Out_ PHANDLE phServerPipe, 
                        _Out_ PHANDLE phClientPipe,
                        _In_ ULONG ClientOptions = FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,
                        _In_ ULONG ServerOptions = 0)
{
    HANDLE hFile;

    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

    UNICODE_STRING NamedPipe = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Device\\NamedPipe\\");
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &NamedPipe, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };

    NTSTATUS status;

    if (0 <= (status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, SYNCHRONIZE, &oa, &iosb, 
           FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0)))
    {
        oa.RootDirectory = hFile;

        LARGE_INTEGER timeout = { 0, MINLONG };
        UNICODE_STRING empty = {};

        oa.ObjectName = &empty;

        if (0 <= (status = ZwCreateNamedPipeFile(phServerPipe,
            FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES|FILE_READ_DATA|
            FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES|FILE_WRITE_DATA|
            FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE|SYNCHRONIZE, 
            &oa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            FILE_CREATE, 
            ServerOptions, 
            FILE_PIPE_BYTE_STREAM_TYPE, FILE_PIPE_BYTE_STREAM_MODE,
            FILE_PIPE_QUEUE_OPERATION, 1, 0, 0, &timeout)))
        {
            oa.RootDirectory = *phServerPipe;
            oa.Attributes = OBJ_INHERIT;

            if (0 > (status = NtOpenFile(phClientPipe, 
                SYNCHRONIZE|FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES|FILE_READ_DATA|
                FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES|FILE_WRITE_DATA, &oa, &iosb, 
                FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, ClientOptions)))
            {
                NtClose(oa.RootDirectory);
                *phServerPipe = 0;
            }
        }

        NtClose(hFile);
    }

    return status;
}

some demo code for asynchronous I/O:
class uIRP;

class __declspec(novtable) IoObj
{
    friend class uIRP;

    HANDLE _M_hFile = 0;
    PTP_IO _M_Io = 0;
    LONG _M_nRef = 1;

    virtual void IOCompletionRoutine(ULONG Code, NTSTATUS status, ULONG_PTR dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, uIRP* Irp) = 0;

protected:

    void StartIo()
    {
        AddRef();
        if (_M_Io) TpStartAsyncIoOperation(_M_Io);
    }

    HANDLE get_File() { return _M_hFile; }

    virtual ~IoObj()
    {
        if (_M_Io) TpReleaseIoCompletion(_M_Io);
        if (_M_hFile) NtClose(_M_hFile);
    }

public:

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_M_nRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_M_nRef)) delete this;
    }

    void Assign(HANDLE hFile)
    {
        _M_hFile = hFile;
    }
};

class uIRP : public IO_STATUS_BLOCK
{
    PVOID _M_pv;
    ULONG _M_Code;
    LONG _M_nRef = 1;

    void OnIoComplete(IoObj* pObj, PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoSB)
    {
        pObj->IOCompletionRoutine(_M_Code, IoSB->Status, IoSB->Information, this);
        pObj->Release();
        Release();
    }

    static VOID NTAPI S_OnIoComplete(
        _Inout_ PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE /*Instance*/,
        _Inout_opt_ PVOID Context,
        _In_ PVOID ApcContext,
        _In_ PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoSB,
        _In_ PTP_IO /*Io*/)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<uIRP*>(ApcContext)->OnIoComplete(reinterpret_cast<IoObj*>(Context), IoSB);
    }

public:

    static NTSTATUS BindIoCompletion(IoObj* pObj, HANDLE hFile)
    {
        return TpAllocIoCompletion(&pObj->_M_Io, hFile, S_OnIoComplete, pObj, 0);
    }

    uIRP(IoObj* pObj, ULONG Code, PVOID pv = 0) : _M_Code(Code), _M_pv(pv)
    {
        Status = STATUS_PENDING;
        Information = 0;
        pObj->StartIo();
    }

    void Reuse(IoObj* pObj, ULONG Code, PVOID pv = 0)
    {
        AddRef();
        _M_Code = Code, _M_pv = pv;
        Status = STATUS_PENDING;
        Information = 0;
        pObj->StartIo();
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_M_nRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_M_nRef)) delete this;
    }

    void CheckNtStatus(IoObj* pObj, NTSTATUS status)
    {
        if (NT_ERROR(status))
        {
            TpCancelAsyncIoOperation(pObj->_M_Io);
            Status = status;
            OnIoComplete(pObj, this);
        }
    }
};

class Pipe : public IoObj
{
    enum { op_write = 'wwww', op_read = 'rrrr' };

    ULONG _M_dwThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    char _M_buf[0x100];

    virtual ~Pipe()
    {
        PostThreadMessageW(_M_dwThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
    }

    NTSTATUS Write(const void* pv, ULONG cb)
    {
        if (uIRP* Irp = new uIRP(this, op_write))
        {
            return Irp->CheckNtStatus(this, 
                NtWriteFile(get_File(), 0, 0, Irp, Irp, const_cast<void*>(pv), cb, 0, 0)), 0;
        }

        return STATUS_NO_MEMORY;
    }

    NTSTATUS Read(uIRP* Irp)
    {
        return Irp->CheckNtStatus(this, 
            NtReadFile(get_File(), 0, 0, Irp, Irp, _M_buf, sizeof(_M_buf), 0, 0)), 0;
    }

    virtual void IOCompletionRoutine(ULONG Code, NTSTATUS status, ULONG_PTR dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, uIRP* Irp)
    {
        if (0 > status)
        {
            DbgPrint("\n%hs<%p>(%.4hs, %x, %x, %p)\n", __FUNCTION__, this, &Code, status, dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, Irp);
            return ;
        }

        switch (Code)
        {
        case op_read:
            if (dwNumberOfBytesTransfered)
            {
                PCHAR psz = _M_buf;
                do 
                {
                    Code = (ULONG)min(0x80, dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
                    
                    DbgPrint("%.*hs", Code, psz);

                    psz += Code;

                } while (dwNumberOfBytesTransfered -= Code);
            }
            Irp->Reuse(this, op_read);
            Read(Irp);
            break;
        case op_write:
            break;
        default:
            __debugbreak();
        }
    }

public:
    NTSTATUS Start(PHANDLE phClient)
    {
        HANDLE hPipe;
        NTSTATUS status = CreatePipePair(&hPipe, phClient);
        if (0 <= status)
        {
            if (0 <= (status = uIRP::BindIoCompletion(this, hPipe)))
            {
                Assign(hPipe);

                if (uIRP* Irp = new uIRP(this, op_read))
                {
                    return Read(Irp);
                }

                status = STATUS_NO_MEMORY;
            }

            NtClose(*phClient);
            *phClient = 0;
        }
        return status;
    }
};

NTSTATUS StartProcess(PCWSTR lpApplicationName, PWSTR lpCommandLine = 0)
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFOEXW si = { { sizeof(si) } };
    si.StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    HRESULT hr;
    SIZE_T s = 0;
    while (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == (hr = BOOL_TO_ERROR(InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(si.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, &s))))
    {
        si.lpAttributeList = (PPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)alloca(s);
    }

    if (NOERROR == hr)
    {
        if (NOERROR == (hr = BOOL_TO_ERROR(UpdateProcThreadAttribute(si.lpAttributeList, 
            0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST, &si.StartupInfo.hStdError, sizeof(HANDLE), 0, 0))))
        {
            hr = STATUS_NO_MEMORY;

            if (Pipe* pipe = new Pipe)
            {
                hr = pipe->Start(&si.StartupInfo.hStdError);
                pipe->Release();

                if (0 <= hr)
                {
                    si.StartupInfo.hStdOutput = si.StartupInfo.hStdError;
                    si.StartupInfo.hStdInput = si.StartupInfo.hStdError;

                    if (CreateProcessW(lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, 0, 0, TRUE, 
                        EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT|DETACHED_PROCESS, 0, 0, &si.StartupInfo, &pi))
                    {
                        NtClose(pi.hThread);
                        NtClose(pi.hProcess);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hr = GetLastError();
                    }

                    NtClose(si.StartupInfo.hStdError);
                }
            }

        }
        DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(si.lpAttributeList);
    }

    return hr;
}

    WCHAR app[0x100];
    if (ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(L"%SystemRoot%\\system32\\ipconfig.exe", app, _countof(app)))
    {
        if (S_OK == StartProcess(app, const_cast<PWSTR>(L"* /?")))
        {
            MSG msg;
            while (0 < GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
            {
            }
        }
    }


The solution, as far as I've understood it, is to add a security descriptor, so I worked along the example given here. At first I thought I would just deny access to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK, but the problem is that once you set up a security descriptor, everything goes from allowed by default to denied by default, so that essentially broke my application. My solution was to allow only the user the process is running under, and deny NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK.
Full disclosure: I am by no means an expert on this, so I am not (yet) marking it as the accepted answer, since I am anything other than sure that this actually seals it up. But from what I've read, it should. Please let me know if I got something wrong, or if everything is right and I can mark this as the accepted answer.
Essentially, I ended up adding this before the code above:
HANDLE processToken;

//get Token of the process this is running in
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_READ, &processToken);
PSID currentUser;

// GetLogonSID method from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa446670(v=vs.85)
GetLogonSID(processToken, &currentUser);

EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea[2];

//give the user the process is running under read and write access
ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ;
ea[0].grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
ea[0].grfInheritance = INHERIT_NO_PROPAGATE;
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_USER;
ea[0].Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)currentUser;
PSID network;

//Initialize NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and deny all rights
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY sidNTAUTHORITY = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
AllocateAndInitializeSid(
    &sidNTAUTHORITY, 
    1, 
    SECURITY_NETWORK_RID, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    &network
    );
ea[1].grfAccessPermissions = STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL | SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL;
ea[1].grfAccessMode = DENY_ACCESS;
ea[1].grfInheritance = SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT;
ea[1].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
ea[1].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
ea[1].Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)network;

//set the entries and create the security descriptor
PACL pACL = NULL;
SetEntriesInAcl(2, ea, NULL, &pACL);
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR descriptor = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(descriptor, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(descriptor, TRUE, pACL, FALSE);

Once that is taken care of, the descriptor can then be set as the lpSecurityDescriptor member of SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES:
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attr;
attr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
attr.lpSecurityDescriptor = descriptor;
attr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

(If anyone is interested in the full working code or if I should post it as part of the answer, please let me know)

Best Solution - create unnamed piper pair. No name - impossible open by name
